# Link function with arguments defined inside a namespace

Tags: c++, xcode, linker

I'm trying to compile an old C++ XCode project that has the following components:

- A very old version of a framework that is compiled along with the project
- A different framework that implements communication with an external device. This framework is already compiled, and we only have access to its binary form.
- Application code

Our effort is aimed to compile the project for the new M1 platform, which requires us to update the framework mentioned in the first bullet.

The binary framework implements a function that takes arguments of types defined in a header from the old framework, and that function is used in the application code as an extern function

```
// Header form the first framework
class A;
class B;

// Binary framework (can't be modified)
void foo(A a, B b);

// Application code
extern void foo(A a, B b);
```

The issue that I'm experiencing is that the most recent version of the new framework declares classes `A` and `B` inside a namespace, so the new scenario is

```
// Header form the first framework
namespace x
{
class A;
class B;
}

// Binary framework (can't be modified)
void foo(A a, B b);

// Application code
extern void foo(x::A a, x::B b);
```

This obviously fails to link `foo`. My question is: Is there a way of tricking the compiler into link the version of foo from the binary framework with the new definition that uses the namespace?

Comment: C has no namespaces. In general C and C++ are two different languages

Comment: I see two possibilities: 1) the vendor of the framework still exists. If so: ask them. 2) THe vendor of the framework doesn't exist. If so: Where do you expect to get the binary for the framework from, compiled for AArch64?

Comment: It may not look like it, but the classes have been renamed, from `::A` (in the global namespace) to `::x::A` (now in a named namespace). This is no different from renaming `class leap` to `class jump`. If you can't modify the framework, you _may_ be able to create proxies with `struct A: public ::x::A` (declared in the global namespace).